# Reading binary data

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

I am trying to read data from a binary file. One block of data is 76 bytes long (this varies with the number of the 2-byte "main data items" in the middle of the block).  The first datum is 4 bytes, second is 4 bytes, and then there are a bunch of 2 byte main data items, and at the end are 2 more 2-byte pieces of data.

[image]

Based on [this Delphi sample](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Rio/en/TBinaryReader_and_TBinaryWriter_(Delphi)) I've learned how to read the file with the code below:

```
short AShortInt; // 16 bits
int AInteger; // 32 bits
try
{
 infile=new TFileStream(myfile,fmOpenRead); // myfile is binary
 BR = new TBinaryReader(infile, TEncoding::Unicode, false);
 for (int rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++) {  // just read the first 5 blocks of data for testing
  AInteger = BR->ReadInt32(); // read first two 4 byte integers for this block
  AInteger = BR->ReadInt32();
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) { // now read the 32 2-byte integers from this block
   AShortInt = BR->ReadInt16();
  }
  AShortInt = BR->ReadInt16(); // read next to last 2-byte int
  AShortInt = BR->ReadInt16(); // read the last 2-byte int
}
delete infile;
delete BR;
Close();
}
catch(...)
{
 delete infile;  // closes the file, doesn't delete it.
 delete BR;
 ShowMessage("Can't open file!");
 Close();
}
```

But, what i would like to do is use a 76-byte wide buffer to read the entire block, and then pick the various datum out of that buffer.  I put together the following code [based on this question](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=816073) and i can read a whole block of data into the buffer.

```
UnicodeString myfile = System::Ioutils::TPath::Combine(System::Ioutils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath(), "binaryCOM.dat");
TFileStream*infile=0;
try
{
 infile=new TFileStream(myfile,fmOpenRead);
 const int bufsize=76;
 char*buf=new char[bufsize];
 int a = 0;
 while(int bytesread=infile->Read(buf,bufsize)) {
   a++; // just a place to break on Run to Cursor
 }
 delete[]buf;
}
catch(...)
{
  delete infile;  
  ShowMessage("Can't open file!");
  Close();
}
```

But i can't figure out how to piece together subsets out of the bytes in the buffer.  Is there a way to **concatenate** **bytes**? So i could read a block of data into a 76 byte buffer and then do something like this below?

```
unsigned int FirstDatum = buf[0]+buf[1]+buf[2]+buf[3];  // concatenate the 4 bytes for the first piece of data
```

This will be an FMX app for Win32, iOS, and Android built in C++Builder 10.3.2.

Comment: Declare a record structure that has those integers and shortints named as you like. Read all 76 bytes in one go to an instance of this structure, then refer the individual fields with their name as you declared them. (I'm just not sure about the endianness on the platforms you mentioned)

Comment: Thanks Tom.  Sorry, one detail i forgot to mention, there will be a variable number of those "2-byte main data items" in between the start and end of a block.  So the block won't always be 76 bytes.   Is there a way to create the struct at run-time so it can accommodate that need for variability?

Comment: You would have to use a dynamically allocated array to read the integers into. That being said, you can still use the `TBinaryReader` to read the individual integers, just read a block of data into a `TMemoryStream` and use that as the reader's input data instead of the `TFileStream`.

Comment: Thanks Remy, i posted my modified code in an answer to keep question clean.  This works very well since the variable length "main data" are always 2-byte signed short integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my modified code using Remy's suggestion of `TMemoryStream`.

```
UnicodeString myfile = System::Ioutils::TPath::Combine(System::Ioutils::TPath::GetDocumentsPath(), "binaryCOM.dat");

TMemoryStream *MS=0;
TBinaryReader *BR=0;
std::vector<short> myArray;
short AShortInt;
int AInteger;
int NumDatums = 32; // the variable number of 2-byte main datums

try
{
  MS = new TMemoryStream();
  MS->LoadFromFile(myfile);
  BR = new TBinaryReader(MS, TEncoding::Unicode, false);
  for (int rows = 0; rows < 5; rows++) {  // testing with first 5 blocks of data
    AInteger = BR->ReadInt32(); // read first two 4 byte integers
    AInteger = BR->ReadInt32(); // here
    for (int i = 0; i < NumDatums; i++) {  // read the main 2-byte data
      AShortInt = BR->ReadInt16();
      myArray.push_back(AShortInt); // push it into vector
    }
    AShortInt = BR->ReadInt16(); // read next to last 2-byte int
    AShortInt = BR->ReadInt16(); // read the last 2-byte int
    // code here to do something with this block of data just read from file
  }
}
delete MS;
delete BR;
}
catch(...)
{
 delete MS;  
 delete BR;
 ShowMessage("Can't open file.");
}
```